# Error with Cisco Anyconnect on Mac OS behind a proxy

Tags: macos, proxy, cisco-anyconnect

I am trying to connect to my corporate VPN using Cisco Anyconnect V.4.7.04056 on Mac Os 10.14.6.

My Mac is on a wired lan that requires the use of a proxy server in order to access the internet. The anyconnect profile I use has the "Native" value for the "ProxySetting" key, so AnyConnect can contact the "HostAddress" (I see that also looking at the mac system log).

When I try to connect, Anyconnect gives me the messages: "Connection attempt has failed", "No valid certificates available for authentication", "Cannot connect to this gateway", and from the mac system log I see that the first error is "CTRANSPORT_ERROR_NON_CISCO_GATEWAY":

```
560 Invoked Function: ConnectMgr::processIfcData Return Code: -29949878 (0xFE37004A) Description: CTRANSPORT_ERROR_NON_CISCO_GATEWAY:we should not connect to non-Cisco gateways Cannot connect to this gateway. Please choose another gateway and try again
```

I know that my certificate is OK because when I am at home (e.g. no proxy) I have no problem to connect.

Several my colleagues in the same environment have no problem using various versions of Anyconnect on Windows 10.

Any advice that helps me to overcome this problem is welcome.